# destroy vs destroy_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to know when to use `:dependent => :destroy_all` and when to use `:dependent => :destroy`

What happen if my model has_many child models, and I used `:dependent => :destroy` ? will it destroy only the first child model ?

is this line of code wrong:

```
has_many books, :dependent => :destroy
```

shall it be like this:

```
has_many books, :dependent => :destroy_all
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will destroy all books. All of them.

```
has_many books, :dependent => :destroy
```

An important thing to remember is that `:dependent => :destroy` will cause the calling of the `#destroy` method in each and every one of the associated Books. By calling `#destroy` on each Book, any `before_destroy` or `after_destroy` callback will be executed for each Book.

Naturally, if you have a LOT of dependent books, this process could be expensive.

The `:destroy_all` is invalid, maybe you were thinking about `:delete_all`. The difference with `:delete_all` (instead of just `:destroy`) is that Rails will issue a single SQL statement to delete all dependent book records. No `#destroy` method will be called on any Book record, and no `before_destroy` or `after_destroy` callback will be executed.

The upside is that a single SQL statement is many times more efficient to delete records from the database than calling `#destroy` on each one of them.

This is very important to know. If you have any `*_destroy` callbacks on the Book model, you should be aware that defining `:dependent => :delete_all` will have the effect of ignoring any callbacks you defined on the Book model.

Comment: Just to be clear: this won't destroy "all books...all of them." It will destroy the books of which this model has_many. The way the first sentence is written, it sounds like Books.all.destroy is what I should expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the first line is correct and the second line is incorrect.

Here's a link to the specific section in the documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options

My understanding is that `:dependent` will loop through the associations and call the given function which means `:destroy` is the correct one to call. (`:destroy_all` is only valid for collections.)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please explain how :destroy_all is only valid for collections?